# Positioning hover sub-menu inside bootstrap megamenu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am playing around with the yamm mega menu for bootstrap. I added a hover menu inside the mega menu. It is not sitting properly. I want the hover menu to line up with the sub menu header and caret. Its sitting below and I want it changed. I tried left and top auto on position absolute, but that doesn't do it.
Codepen is here:http://codepen.io/iamgonge/pen/qrqQBK

here is the mega menu and hover sub menu code:

```
  <header>
   <!-- Fixed navbar -->
   <nav class="navbar agmm navbar-scroll navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" id="topnavbar">
      <div class="container">
         <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" title="frontpage">Logo here</a>
         </div>
         <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <!--Wayfinder.outerTpl -->
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
               <!-- Wayfinder.parentRowTpl -->
               <li class="first dropdown agmm-fw">
                  <a href="#" title="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">megamenu Level 1<b class="caret"></b></a>
                  <!--Wayfinder.innerTpl -->
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu ">
                     <!-- agmm start tags -->
                     <li>
                        <div class="agmm-content">
                           <div class="row">
                              <dl class="col-sm-15 mega-menu">
                                 <!-- Wayfinder.categoryFoldersTpl -->
                                 <dt class="first"><a href="#">Microsoft Office</a></dt>
                                 <!--Wayfinder.innerTpl -->
                                 <dd class="first">
                     <li class="hover_drop_down">
                     <a href="#">Remote Desktop Services 2016<span class="caret"></span></a>    
                     <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" id="office">
                     <li><a href="#">Office 2016 Home & Business</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Office 2016 Home & Business</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Office 2016 Home & Business</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Office 2016 Home & Business</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Office 2016 Home & Business</a></li>
                     </ul>
                     </li></dd>
                     <dd class="first"> <li class="hover_drop_down">
                     <a href="#">Remote Desktop Services 2016<span class="caret"></span></a>    
                     <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" id="office">
                     <li><a href="#">Office 2016 Home & Business</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Office 2016 Home & Business</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Office 2016 Home & Business</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Office 2016 Home & Business</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Office 2016 Home & Business</a></li>
                     </ul>
                     </li></dd>
                     <dd class="last"> <li class="hover_drop_down">
                     <a href="#">Remote Desktop Services 2016<span class="caret"></span></a>    
                     <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                     <li><a href="#">Office 2016 Home & Business</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Office 2016 Home & Business</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Office 2016 Home & Business</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Office 2016 Home & Business</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Office 2016 Home & Business</a></li>
                     </ul>
                     </li></dd>
                     </dl>

                     <dl class="col-sm-15 mega-menu">
                     <!-- Wayfinder.categoryFoldersTpl -->
                     <dt class="first"><a href="#">Microsoft Office</a></dt>
                     <!--Wayfinder.innerTpl -->
                     <dd class="first"><li class="hover_drop_down">
                     <a href="#">Microsoft Office 2016<span class="caret"></span></a>    
                     <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                     <li><a href="#">Office 2016 Home & Business</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Office 2016 Home & Business</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Office 2016 Home & Business</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Office 2016 Home & Business</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Office 2016 Home & Business</a></li>
                     </ul>
                     </li></dd>
                     <dd><a href="#">Child on level 7</a></dd>
                     <dd class="last"><a href="#">Child on level 3</a></dd>
                     </dl>

                     <dl class="col-sm-15 mega-menu">
                     <!-- Wayfinder.categoryFoldersTpl -->
                     <dt class="first"><a href="#">Microsoft Office</a></dt>
                     <!--Wayfinder.innerTpl -->
                     <dd class="first"><li class="hover_drop_down">
                     <a href="#">Microsoft Office 2016<span class="caret"></span></a>    
                     <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                     <li><a href="#">Office 2016 Home & Business</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Office 2016 Home & Business</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Office 2016 Home & Business</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Office 2016 Home & Business</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Office 2016 Home & Business</a></li>
                     </ul>
                     </li></dd>
                     <dd><a href="#">Child on level 7</a></dd>
                     <dd class="last"><a href="#">Child on level 3</a></dd>
                     </dl>
                     <dl class="col-sm-15 mega-menu">
                     <!-- Wayfinder.categoryFoldersTpl -->
                     <dt class="first"><a href="#">Microsoft Office</a></dt>
                     <!--Wayfinder.innerTpl -->
                     <dd class="first"><li class="hover_drop_down">
                     <a href="#">Microsoft Office 2016<span class="caret"></span></a>    
                     <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                     <li><a href="#">Office 2016 Home & Business</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Office 2016 Home & Business</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Office 2016 Home & Business</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Office 2016 Home & Business</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Office 2016 Home & Business</a></li>
                     </ul>
                     </li></dd>
                     <dd><a href="#">Child on level 7</a></dd>
                     <dd class="last"><a href="#">Child on level 3</a></dd>
                     </dl>

                     <dl class="col-sm-15 mega-menu">
                     <!-- Wayfinder.categoryFoldersTpl -->
                     <dt class="first"><a href="#">Microsoft Office</a></dt>
                     <!--Wayfinder.innerTpl -->
                     <dd class="first"><li class="hover_drop_down">
                     <a href="#">Microsoft Office 2016<span class="caret"></span></a>    
                     <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                     <li><a href="#">Office 2016 Home & Business</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Office 2016 Home & Business</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Office 2016 Home & Business</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Office 2016 Home & Business</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Office 2016 Home & Business</a></li>
                     </ul>
                     </li></dd>
                     <dd><a href="#">Child on level 7</a></dd>
                     <dd class="last"><a href="#">Child on level 3</a></dd>
                     </dl>

                     <dl class="col-sm-15 mega-menu">
                     <!-- Wayfinder.categoryFoldersTpl -->
                     <dt class="first"><a href="#">Microsoft Office</a></dt>
                     <!--Wayfinder.innerTpl -->
                     <dd class="first"><li class="hover_drop_down">
                     <a href="#">Microsoft Office 2016<span class="caret"></span></a>    
                     <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                     <li><a href="#">Office 2016 Home & Business</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Office 2016 Home & Business</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Office 2016 Home & Business</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Office 2016 Home & Business</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Office 2016 Home & Business</a></li>
                     </ul>
                     </li></dd>
                     <dd><a href="#">Child on level 7</a></dd>
                     <dd class="last"><a href="#">Child on level 3</a></dd>
                     </dl>
                     </div>
                     </div>
                     </li>
                     <!--agmm end tags-->
                  </ul>
               </li>
               <li class=" dropdown">
                  <a href="#" title="Referanser" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                  Standard Level 1<b class="caret"></b></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                     <li class="first"><a href="#">Level 2</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Level 2</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Level 2</a></li>
                     <li> <a href="#">Level 2</a></li>
                  </ul>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </div>
         <!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
   </nav>
</header>
```

Here is the css:

```
/* Hover dropdown */
.dropdown ul.dropdown-menu {
    margin-top: 0;

}
#office{position: absolute;
left:200px;
z-index: 1000;}
/*To avoid unwanted close*/
.hover_drop_down:hover ul.dropdown-menu {

    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: auto;
    left: auto;

    z-index: 1000;
  width: 100%;
}
.dropdown-menu>li>a {
   display: block;
  margin: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 1;
    color: #599ab9;

}
```

Comment: actually i think its more of a css issue. the class is hover_drop_down. Its alot clearer if you look at the codepen

Comment: look my answer i tried my fix out and it works. if at least u mean the left dropdowns arent working becouse they open randomly somewhere

Comment: is this your requirement http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VpmNYL?

Comment: no, I dont know how else to explain this. I want the hover menus to open to the right of the caret inside the mega-menu. When you hover the menu should open directly to the right, not below ,not half under. It needs to be to the right and aligned vertically with either the top of the lettering or the caret.

Answer (score 0):

Well i opened up the code. and Copy pasted the one in the bottom left corner and pasted it in the one above that and the one above the other one.

```
     <dd class="last"> <li class="hover_drop_down">
                 <a href="#">Remote Desktop Services 2016<span class="caret"></span></a>    
                 <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                 <li><a href="#">Office 2016 Home & Business</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Office 2016 Home & Business</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Office 2016 Home & Business</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Office 2016 Home & Business</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Office 2016 Home & Business</a></li>
                 </ul>
                 </li></dd>
```

replace the other ones. i presume this was what u wanted.

i found out  `<dd class="last">` is the tag you want to use. and not `<dd class="first">`

Comment: Not quite. I want the hover sub menu that shows up when you hover over the first careted item in the megamenu(remote services) to align with the top of thaat entry or the caret, right now when it open it sits below and not far enough to the right.

Comment: oh well. then this isnt the solution :P